# Alternative to importing global es6 constant

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm developing a WordPress theme using Sage 9 and am trying to split my files up for cleaner code for cleaner code. I'm using webpack to bundle JavaScript locally.

There is a router set up to only run JavaScript on certain pages. However when I try to import the file contents as a constant, it is globally scoped and causes issues on the homepage. The following example should better explain:

```js
// formPage.js (the init function is only run on the form page)
import { validateAge } from '../modules/validateAge';
export default {
  init() {
    // Javascript to be fired on the form page
    new validateAge();
  },
};

// ../modules/validateAge.js
export const validateAge = Marionette.Object.extend({
  ...
}
```

How can I rewrite this without having the marionette object scoped globally? This fails on the homepage since the Marionette dependency is only loaded on the form page (separately from the bundle) and not the home page.

Comment: Can you have `validateAge` `import` `Marionette`, so `Marionette` isn't global?

Comment: export marionette from `formPage.js` and import it in your `validateAge.js`

Comment: Trouble is, Marionette is loaded separately by Wordpress further up the page so if I es6 import it from npm I'll have duplicate dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed this by exporting as a function rather than a constant therefore scoping the Marionette call.